# How do I assign a variable with the first selected value in Postgres syntax?

Tags: postgresql

I try this:

```
myvar := select "name" from "mytable" where "id" = 15;
```

But it causes an error. How can I assign the variable correctly?

Comment: `select "name" into myvar from "mytable" where "id" = 15;`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select "name" into myvar from "mytable" where "id" = 15;`

or

`myvar := (select "name" from "mytable" where "id" = 15);`

Answer (score 1):

It will work when you are using the `INTO` Keyword like

```
select "name" into myvar from "mytable" where "id" = 15;
```

But its possible that this returns more than one row. (Throws an Error in Oracle-SQL, cant speak for Postgres)

I think somithing like

```
select "name" into myvar from "mytable" where "id" = 15 limit 1;
```

would be better to fit your question title.